# Gutenberg: Block validation failed

Tags: block-editor

I am using custom block to generate shotcode that then renders the HTML.

When I add the block and save the post, everything works, the block renders the shortcode with its default values.

When I change some values, the post saves without error and works on frontend.

But when I reload the posts edit page I get the following error:

```
Block validation: Block validation failed for `fare/list-posts` ( 
Object { name: "fare/list-posts", icon: {…}, attributes: {…}, keywords: [],   save: save(t), title: "List Posts", category: "common", edit: edit(e)
 }
).

Content generated by `save` function:

[list-posts type="post" category="" count="6"][/list-posts]

Content retrieved from post body:

[list-posts type="post" category="" count="12"][/list-posts]
```

The validation expects default values but gets the new edited shortcode with new values.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
/* This section of the code registers a new block, sets an icon and a category, and indicates what type of fields it'll include. */
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('fare/list-posts', {
  title: 'List Posts',
  icon: 'tickets',
  category: 'common',
  attributes: {
    posttype: {
      type: 'string',
      default: 'post'
    },
    postcategory: {
      type: 'string',
      default: ''
    },
    postcount: {
      type: 'number',
      default: 6
    },
  },

  /* This configures how the content and color fields will work, and sets up the necessary elements */
  edit: function(props) {
    function updatePostType(event) {
      props.setAttributes({posttype: event.target.value})
    }
    function updateCategory(event) {
      props.setAttributes({postcategory: event.target.value})
    }
    function updatePostCount(event) {
      props.setAttributes({postcount: event.target.value})
    }
    return React.createElement("div",{ style: { border: '2px solid #aaaaaa', 'border-radius': '3px', padding: '12px'}},
      React.createElement( "h3", null, "List Posts" ),
      React.createElement( "span", { style: { margin: '0' }}, "Post Type" ),
      React.createElement( "input", { type: "text", value: props.attributes.posttype, onChange: updatePostType, style: {} }),
      React.createElement( "hr" ),
      React.createElement( "span", { style: { margin: '0' }}, "Post Category" ),
      React.createElement( "input", { type: "text", value: props.attributes.postcategory, onChange: updateCategory, style: {} }),
      React.createElement( "hr" ),
      React.createElement( "span", { style: { margin: '0' }}, "Post Count" ),
      React.createElement( "input", { type: "number", value: props.attributes.postcount, onChange: updatePostCount, style: {} })
    )
  },

  save: function(props) {
    //
    return '[list-posts type="'+props.attributes.posttype+'" category="'+props.attributes.postcategory+'" count="'+props.attributes.postcount+'"][/list-posts]';
  }
})
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### In short, when saving an attribute, make sure its *type* matches the one that you defined in the block's `attributes` option.

The [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-attributes/#considerations) says:

> Lastly, make sure that you respect the data’s type when setting
>   attributes, as the framework does not automatically perform type
>   casting of meta. Incorrect typing in block attributes will result in a
>   post remaining dirty even after saving (*cf.* `isEditedPostDirty`,
>   `hasEditedAttributes`). For instance, if `authorCount` is an integer,
>   remember that event handlers may pass a *different kind of data*, thus
>   the value should be cast explicitly:
>
> ```
> function onChange( event ) {
>   props.setAttributes( { authorCount: Number( event.target.value ) } );
> }
> ```

So the problem is with the `postcount` attribute, which is defined as a number, yet saved as a string (`event.target.value`, in your case, is a string).

And with your code now, if you set the `postcategory` to `foo` and the `postcount` to something else than `6`, e.g. `3`, the block HTML output would be:

```html
<!-- wp:fare/list-posts {"postcategory":"foo"} -->
[list-posts type="post" category="foo" count="3"][/list-posts]
<!-- /wp:fare/list-posts -->
```

but it should actually be — note the `"postcount":3`:

```html
<!-- wp:fare/list-posts {"postcategory":"foo","postcount":3} -->
[list-posts type="post" category="foo" count="3"][/list-posts]
<!-- /wp:fare/list-posts -->
```

And here's the problematic code:

```js
// In updatePostCount()
props.setAttributes({postcount: event.target.value})
```

which should be written as:

```js
props.setAttributes({postcount: Number( event.target.value )})
```

I.e. You need to explicitly cast the value to a number and *not* passing the value as-is (a string).

Comment: kinda crazy this doesn't throw an error in setAttributes