# Gutenberg: Block SelectControl saves attributes but after a reload of Gutenberg it loads its defaults. Why?

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I thought I had it. I added an attribute "max_level" and a SelectControl element "SelectMaxLevel". Everything works according to plan: I can set the max level and it is saved in the block. When I save the post and display the post see that the php part uses the "maximum level" variable. But when I edit the post the blocks loads it's default value. Why does this happen?

```
registerBlockType('simpletoc/toc', {
  title: __('SimpleTOC', 'simpletoc'),
  icon: simpletocicon,
  category: 'layout',
  attributes: {
        no_title: {
            type: 'boolean',
      default: false,
        },
        max_level: {
            type: 'integer',
      default: 6,
        },
    },
  edit: function(props) {

    return (
    <span>
    <InspectorControls>
      <Panel>
        <PanelBody>
          <PanelRow>
            <ToggleControl
                label={__("Disable heading", 'simpletoc')}
                help={__('Remove "Table of contents" block heading.', 'simpletoc')}
                checked={ props.attributes.no_title }
                onChange={ () => props.setAttributes( {  no_title: ! props.attributes.no_title } ) }
            />
          </PanelRow>
          <PanelRow>
            <SelectControl
                label={__("Maximum Level", 'simpletoc')}
                help={__('Maximum depth of the headings.', 'simpletoc')}
                value= { props.attributes.max_level }
                options={ [
                    { label: __('Including', 'simpletoc') + ' H6 (' + __('Show all', 'simpletoc') + ')' , value: '6' },
                    { label: __('Including', 'simpletoc') + ' H5', value: '5' },
                    { label: __('Including', 'simpletoc') + ' H4', value: '4' },
                    { label: __('Including', 'simpletoc') + ' H3', value: '3' },
                    { label: __('Including', 'simpletoc') + ' H2', value: '2' },
                ] }
                onChange={ ( level ) => props.setAttributes( { max_level: level } ) }
            />
          </PanelRow>
        </PanelBody>
      </Panel>
    </InspectorControls>
    <BlockControls>
      <ToolbarGroup>
        <ToolbarButton
          className="components-icon-button components-toolbar__control"
          label={__('Update table of contents', 'simpletoc')}
          onClick={function() {
            sendfakeAttribute(props)
          }}
          icon="update"
        />
      </ToolbarGroup>
  </BlockControls>
  <p>
    <ServerSideRender block={props.name} attributes={props.attributes} />
  </p>
  </span>
    )
  },
  save: props => {
    return null;
  },
});
```

The relevant php part:

```
register_block_type('simpletoc/toc', [
    'editor_script' => 'simpletoc-js',
    'editor_style' => 'simpletoc-editor',
        'attributes' => array(
                'no_title' => array(
                    'type' => 'boolean',
              'default' => false,
                ),
            'max_level' => array(
                    'type' => 'integer',
              'default' => 6,
                ),
            'updated' => array(
              'type' => 'number',
              'default' => 0,
              '_builtIn' => true,
            ),
    ),
    'render_callback' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\\render_callback'
   ]);
```

Comment: I would suggest using `useState` instead, but in this case there is no need for the component to have state at all, and it may even be the cause of your problem! Setting the attribute just sets the attribute locally. Blocks and attributes are saved when the  post is saved, there is no need to use component state here

Comment: Also, why is `attributes` defined twice?

Comment: Man, I wanted to be cool and use you useState and now it is not needed? 

I tried this without the constant but it not working at all: 

<PanelRow><SelectControllabel={__("MaximumLevel",'simpletoc')}help={__('Maximumdepthoftheheadings.','simpletoc')}value={props.attributes.max_level}options={[{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H6('+__('Showall','simpletoc')+')',value:'6'},{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H2',value:'2'},]}onChange={(level)=>{setState(props.setAttributes({max_level:level}))}}/></PanelRow>

Comment: Attributes is defined in php and js. I thought I had to do this.

Comment: This does not work either: 

<PanelRow><SelectControllabel={__("MaximumLevel",'simpletoc')}help={__('Maximumdepthoftheheadings.','simpletoc')}value={props.attributes.max_level}options={[{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H6('+__('Showall','simpletoc')+')',value:'6'},{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H5',value:'5'},{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H4',value:'4'},{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H3',value:'3'},{label:__('Including','simpletoc')+'H2',value:'2'},]}onChange={(level)=>props.setAttributes({max_level:level})}/></PanelRow></PanelBody>

Comment: I fixed the double definition of "attributes" part. But that was not the problem

Comment: I edited my answer with your two suggestion fixed: no useState and correct attribute variable. Still it loads its defaults

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the block editor uses the default value — for the `max_level` ("Maximum level") attribute only — instead of the one parsed from the (block [comment delimiter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/architecture/key-concepts/) in the) *saved* post content, is because in the parsed/saved attributes, `max_level` is invalid.

*Why is it invalid: Because the **type** of the attribute (value) doesn't match the one defined when the block is registered — `max_level: { type: 'integer', ... }`.*

And why doesn't it match, is because this part which updates the attribute with a value that is a string:

```js
// "level" here is an input value, and input values are string unless
// explicitly converted to another type (boolean, number, etc.):

onChange={ ( level ) => props.setAttributes( { max_level: level } ) }
```

Which then, for instance when the "Including H3" is selected as the "Maximum level", results in `"max_level":"3"` instead of the correct one, `"max_level":3`:

- Bad — `max_level` is a string: `<!-- wp:simpletoc/toc {"max_level":"3"} /-->`
- Good — `max_level` is an integer: `<!-- wp:simpletoc/toc {"max_level":3} /-->`

So be sure to respect the attribute **type** and in your case, you would want to use `Number( level )` like so:

```js
props.setAttributes( { max_level: Number( level ) } )
```

BTW, I could've just pointed you to [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/358657), but I thought it'd be better if I write an answer specific to this very question. :)

### Additional Notes

- The `ServerSideRender` component uses [`wp.element.RawHTML()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-element/#RawHTML) which wraps the output in a `div`, hence you shouldn't wrap the `ServerSideRender` in a `p`, which (in my case) resulted in an error (in the console) which says, "*`<div>` cannot be a descendant of `<p>`*" ( in fact, the regular HTML `<p><div>something</div></p>` is indeed invalid :) ). So,

  ```js
  // Instead of this:
  <p><ServerSideRender .../></p>

  // Use a div or Fragment as a wrapper:
  <div><ServerSideRender .../></div>
  <><ServerSideRender .../></>

  // Or simply, no wrapper:
  <ServerSideRender .../>
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I will thank you and Tom J Nowell for helping me with this plugin in the credits. I learn so much.

Comment: Glad it helped! And I hope the additional note also helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. I will change that asap

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! very important this part " respect the attribute type"

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining, this is excellent!